# Where should I store my Jasmine files in a Symfony project?

Tags: javascript, symfony, jasmine

What is the best place to put the Jasmine files (libs, specs, SpecRunner.html)
in a symfony project?

I would make in this way:

the jasmine libs in `web/vendor/js`

the spec files in `src/myProject/WebBundle/Resources/public/js`

and the `SpecRunner.html` I have no idea.

Comment: "I have no idea".. i like the honesty..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Jasmine is used just for testing your JavaScript code, I don't think it is a good idea to put libraries and spec files in the public.

I would put them in `src/myProject/WebBundle/Resources/`

```
src/myProject/WebBundle/Resources/js/lib/jasmine
src/myProject/WebBundle/Resources/js/spec
```